# Haskell - Actor based mutability

Tags: multithreading, haskell, request, actor, channel

I'm working on a haskell network application and I use the actor pattern to manage multithreading. One thing I came across is how to store for example a set of client sockets/handles. Which of course must be accessible for all threads and can change when clients log on/off.

Since I'm coming from the imperative world I thought about some kind of lock-mechanism but when I noticed how ugly this is I thought about "pure" mutability, well actually it's kind of pure:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Network
import System.IO
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import System.Environment
import Control.Exception


newStorage :: (Eq a, Show a) => IO (Chan (String, Maybe (Chan [a]), Maybe a))
newStorage = do
  q <- newChan
  forkIO $ storage [] q
  return q


newHandleStorage :: IO (Chan (String, Maybe (Chan [Handle]), Maybe Handle))
newHandleStorage = newStorage


storage :: (Eq a, Show a) => [a] -> Chan (String, Maybe (Chan [a]), Maybe a) -> IO ()
storage s q = do
  let loop = (`storage` q)
  (req, reply, d) <- readChan q
  print ("processing " ++ show(d))
  case req of
    "add" -> loop ((fromJust d) : s)
    "remove" -> loop (delete (fromJust d) s)
    "get" -> do
      writeChan (fromJust reply) s
      loop s


store s d = writeChan s ("add", Nothing, Just d)
unstore s d = writeChan s ("remove", Nothing, Just d)
request s = do
  chan <- newChan
  writeChan s ("get", Just chan, Nothing)
  readChan chan
```

The point is that a thread (actor) is managing a list of items and modifies the list according to incoming requests. Since thread are really cheap I thought this could be a really nice functional alternative.

Of course this is just a prototype (a quick dirty proof of concept).
So my question is:

1. Is this a "good" way of managing shared mutable variables (in the actor world) ?
2. Is there already a library for this pattern ? (I already searched but I found nothing)

Regards,
Chris

Comment: If you're willing to explore alternatives to the actor model, I'd suggest you to try out Haskell's [Software Transactional Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory). It's a beautiful mechanism similar to database transactions. See [Chapter 28](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/software-transactional-memory.html) in The Real World Haskell.

Comment: Technically a great choice but I heard that using STM with a large number of threads (one thread per client which is standard in haskell) and relatively long operations (deleting an item from a list is O(n), of course hash sets/maps could help here) could reduce the performance of STM by a large number. And of course the MVar Channel could be replaced by the STM Channel which means using the best of the two techniques. EDIT: The actor pattern is generally really nice in such a situation, becuase deleting/adding an item is O(1) (just sending a message) The actual work is done in a thread...

Comment: You're right. With STM it can happen that transactions are restarted multiple times, leading to reduced performance. But if your synchronized operations take long, you can get to similar problems with actors as well - if there are more messages than it can handle, its state will lag behind the reality. So using balanced trees (`Map`/`Set`) or `ST/IO`-based hash sets would definitely help.

Comment: Perhaps an interesting and fun solution would be to create a balanced tree with nodes handled as STM variables (or a similar hash set). This way it would be possible for different threads to update different parts of the tree simultaneously.

Comment: Definitely a good solution as well. I just like the actor concept, but this solution might be better, maybe using actors for every piece of concurrency is kind of overkill. But actors are pretty easy to use which is pretty attractive, too.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick and dirty example using `stm` and `pipes-network`.  This will set up a simple server that allows clients to connect and increment or decrement a counter.  It will display a very simple status bar showing the current tallies of all connected clients and will remove client tallies from the bar when they disconnect.

First I will begin with the server, and I've generously commented the code to explain how it works:

```
import Control.Concurrent.STM (STM, atomically)
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H
import Data.Foldable (forM_)

import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (unless)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.TCP
import System.IO

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering

    {- These are the internal data structures.  They should be an implementation
       detail and you should never expose these references to the
       "business logic" part of the application. -}
    -- I use nRef to keep track of creating fresh Ints (which identify users)
    nRef <- newTVarIO 0       :: IO (TVar Int)
    {- hMap associates every user (i.e. Int) with a counter

       Notice how I've "striped" the hash map by storing STM references to the
       values instead of storing the values directly.  This means that I only
       actually write the hashmap when adding or removing users, which reduces
       contention for the hash map.

       Since each user gets their own unique STM reference for their counter,
       modifying counters does not cause contention with other counters or
       contention with the hash map. -}
    hMap <- newTVarIO H.empty :: IO (TVar (H.HashMap Int (TVar Int)))

    {- The following code makes heavy use of Haskell's pure closures.  Each
       'let' binding closes over its current environment, which is safe since
        Haskell is pure. -}

    let {- 'getCounters' is the only server-facing command in our STM API.  The
           only permitted operation is retrieving the current set of user
           counters.

           'getCounters' closes over the 'hMap' reference currently in scope so
           that the server never needs to be aware about our internal
           implementation. -}
        getCounters :: STM [Int]
        getCounters = do
            refs <- fmap H.elems (readTVar hMap)
            mapM readTVar refs

        {- 'init' is the only client-facing command in our STM API.  It
            initializes the client's entry in the hash map and returns two
            commands: the first command is what the client calls to 'increment'
            their counter and the second command is what the client calls to log
            off and delete
            'delete' command.

            Notice that those two returned commands each close over the client's
            unique STM reference so the client never needs to be aware of how
            exactly 'init' is implemented under the hood. -}
        init :: STM (STM (), STM ())
        init = do
            n   <- readTVar nRef
            writeTVar nRef $! n + 1

            ref <- newTVar 0
            modifyTVar' hMap (H.insert n ref)

            let incrementRef :: STM ()
                incrementRef = do
                    mRef <- fmap (H.lookup n) (readTVar hMap)
                    forM_ mRef $ \ref -> modifyTVar' ref (+ 1)

                deleteRef :: STM ()
                deleteRef = modifyTVar' hMap (H.delete n)

            return (incrementRef, deleteRef)

    {- Now for the actual program logic.  Everything past this point only uses
       the approved STM API (i.e. 'getCounters' and 'init').  If I wanted I
       could factor the above approved STM API into a separate module to enforce
       the encapsulation boundary, but I am lazy. -}

    {- Fork a thread which polls the current state of the counters and displays
       it to the console.  There is a way to implement this without polling but
       this gets the job done for now.

       Most of what it is doing is just some simple tricks to reuse the same
       console line instead of outputting a stream of lines.  Otherwise it
       would be just:

       forkIO $ forever $ do
           ns <- atomically getCounters
           print ns
    -}
    forkIO $ (`evalStateT` 0) $ forever $ do
        del <- get
        lift $ do
            putStr (replicate del '\b')
            putStr (replicate del ' ' )
            putStr (replicate del '\b')
        ns <- lift $ atomically getCounters
        let str = show ns
        lift $ putStr str
        put $! length str
        lift $ threadDelay 10000

    {- Fork a thread for each incoming connection, which listens to the client's
       commands and translates them into 'STM' actions -}
    serve HostAny "8080" $ \(socket, _) -> do
        (increment, delete) <- atomically init

        {- Right now, just do the dumb thing and convert all keypresses into
           increment commands, with the exception of the 'q' key, which will
           quit -}
        let handler :: (Proxy p) => () -> Consumer p Char IO ()
            handler () = runIdentityP loop
              where
                loop = do
                    c <- request ()
                    unless (c == 'q') $ do
                        lift $ atomically increment
                        loop

        {- This uses my 'pipes' library.  It basically is a high-level way to
           say:

           * Read binary packets from the socket no bigger than 4096 bytes

           * Get the first character from each packet and discard the rest

           * Handle the character using the above 'handler' function -}
        runProxy $ socketReadS 4096 socket >-> mapD B.head >-> handler

        {- The above pipeline finishes either when the socket closes or
           'handler' stops looping because it received a 'q'.  Either case means
           that the client is done so we log them out using 'delete'. -}
        atomically delete
```

Next up is the client, which simply opens a connections and forwards all key presses as single packets:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Safe
import Control.Proxy.TCP.Safe
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack)
import System.IO

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    hSetEcho      stdin False

    {- Again, this uses my 'pipes' library.  It basically says:

        * Read characters from the console using 'commands'

        * Pack them into a binary format

        * send them to a server running at 127.0.0.1:8080

        This finishes looping when the user types a 'q' or the connection is
        closed for whatever reason.
    -}
    runSafeIO $ runProxy $ runEitherK $
         try . commands
     >-> mapD (\c -> pack [c])
     >-> connectWriteD Nothing "127.0.0.1" "8080"

commands :: (Proxy p) => () -> Producer p Char IO ()
commands () = runIdentityP loop
  where
    loop = do
        c <- lift getChar
        respond c
        unless (c == 'q') loop
```

It's pretty simple: `commands` generates a stream of `Char`s, which then get converted to `ByteString`s and then sent as packets to the server.

If you run the server and a few clients and have them each type in a few keys, your server display will output a list showing how many keys each client typed:

```
[1,6,4]
```

... and if some of the clients disconnect they will be removed from the list:

```
[1,4]
```

Note that the `pipes` component of these examples will simplify greatly in the upcoming `pipes-4.0.0` release, but the current `pipes` ecosystem still gets the job done as is.

Comment: Awesome solution, I will definitely think about it ;)

Comment: Just for my understanding: Is STM considered pure ? I guess it's not since it is all about mutability without using a locking mechanism, right ?

Comment: @Kr0e Right.  Think of STM as composable, thread-safe mutable memory references.

Comment: When I first read about Haskell everybody was saying that mutable stuff is really evil and should be avoided and only used if there is no way around it. As a beginner I'm still quite confused about this issue since STM is obviously one of haskell strenghts but it violates the core concept, doesn't it ? Or is mutability "ok" if it is explicitly tracked by a monad ? I'm really looking for some kind of guideline when to use mutability capabilities.

Comment: @Kr0e If you don't don't use explicit threads (only `par` and similar pure constructions), you don't need to deal with mutability and state. But once you start using concurrency, that is working explicitly with threads, and you want them to communicate somehow, there has to be some mutable state (that is values changing over time), somehow shared and visible across the threads. So if you need to utilize multpile cpu cores, you have 2 options: Keeping things pure and use parallelism only, or use concurrency and deal with thread inter-communication in a mutable world.

Comment: That's why I like the actor pattern where shared mutability usage is limited to the MVar or TVar used in the Channel implementation and the rest works mostly with immutability.

Comment: @Kr0e With STM it's the same - you use only `MVar`s or `TVar`s, nothing more. But with STM it's easier to create atomic components and compose them to complex expressions.

Comment: @Kr0e If you want to use the actor pattern, I recommend you check out my `pipes-concurrency` library which implements a limited form of actors using `pipes`.  The tutorial is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes-concurrency/1.2.1/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Concurrent-Tutorial.html).

Comment: Yeah, thats right. The pipes concept is really strong and can be used for a lot of problems, maybe all ;) I admit that the actor pattern has some drawbacks too, but the good thing about the actor pattern is that it is really easy to reason about correctness. Since every actor has a designated role which improves modularity. But I have to admit, that the STM-container solution might be better in this case, too. BTW: The pipes-concurrency module is equally awesome.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd definitely recommend using your own specific data type for representing commands. When using `(String, Maybe (Chan [a]), Maybe a)` a buggy client can crash your actor simply by sending an unknown command or by sending `("add", Nothing, Nothing)`, etc. I'd suggest something like

```
data Command a = Add a | Remove a | Get (Chan [a])
```

Then you can pattern match on commands in `storage` in a save way.

Actors have their advantages, but also I feel that they have some drawbacks. For example, getting an answer from an actor requires sending it a command and then waiting for a reply. And the client can't be completely sure that it gets a reply and that the reply will be of some specific type - you can't say I want only answers of this type (and how many of them) for this particular command.

So as an example I'll give a simple, STM solution. It'd be better to use a hash table or a (balanced tree) set, but since `Handle` implements neither `Ord` nor `Hashable`, we can't use these data structures, so I'll keep using lists.

```
module ThreadSet (
    TSet, add, remove, get
) where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.STM
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar
import Data.List (delete)

newtype TSet a = TSet (TVar [a])

add :: (Eq a) => a -> TSet a -> STM ()
add x (TSet v) = readTVar v >>= writeTVar v . (x :)

remove :: (Eq a) => a -> TSet a -> STM ()
remove x (TSet v) = readTVar v >>= writeTVar v . delete x

get :: (Eq a) => TSet a -> STM [a]
get (TSet v) = readTVar v
```

This module implements a `STM` based set of arbitrary elements. You can have multiple such sets and use them together in a single `STM` transaction that succeeds or fails at once. For example

```
-- | Ensures that there is exactly one element `x` in the set.
add1 :: (Eq a) => a -> TSet a -> STM ()
add1 x v = remove x v >> add x v
```

This would be difficult with actors, you'd have to add it as another command for the actor, you can't compose it of existing actions and still have atomicity.

**Update:** There is an interesting [article](http://clojure.org/state#actors) explaining why Clojure designers chose not to use actors. For example, using actors, even if you have many reads and only very little writes to a mutable structure, they're all serialized, which can greatly impact performance.

Comment: Well, serializing/deserializing does cost a lot, this is true. CloudHaskell does have the same "serialization-overhead", they call it a feature. But lately they added an unsafe send function which passes the message without ser./deser. which is an order of magnitude faster. Theoretically message passing should be as cheap as a simple function call to make the actor-pattern a real alternative, which, of course, isn't the case but in Erlang it is. I think STM is a really great feature, maybe using both techniques is the way to go, since STM is really low-level compared to the actor-pattern.